# не блокирующий tcp-client на ассемблере

Tags: linux, ассемблер, x86-64, yasm

Следущий код tcp-client'а на ассемблере при запуске выдает ошибку в recvfrom
- EAGAIN, как исправить?

```
    ;; yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf64 -a x86 tcp.asm -o tcp.o
    ;; ld -o tcp tcp.o

    %define EINPROGRESS             -115
    %define EAGAIN                  -11


    segment .bss

listen_socket:  resq 1
read_fdset: resb 2  

    segment .data

packet istruc message
    at message.length_mes,          dw  0x2800
        at message.message_id,          dw  0x0100
        at message.scheme_id,           dw  0x0100
        at message.version,     dw  0x0100
        at message.timestamp,           dq  0
        at message.keeepaliveinterval,  dd  0xe8030000
        at message.credentials,         dq  0
        at message.ext,             dw  0
iend

pop_sa istruc sockaddr_in
        at sockaddr_in.sin_family,  dw 2             ; AF_INET
        at sockaddr_in.sin_port,    dw 0x2823        ; port 9000
        at sockaddr_in.sin_addr,    dd 0xf4e8d05b    ; 91.208.232.244
        at sockaddr_in.sin_zero,    dd 0, 0
iend
sockaddr_in_len     equ $ - pop_sa


timeval: ;struct
        tv_sec  dq 0
        tv_usec dq 0

timeout: ;struct
        to_sec  dq 1
        to_usec dq 0   ;500000

buffer      times 512 db 0x0

    segment .text
    global _start

_start:

struc message
    .length_mes             resw 1
    .message_id             resw 1
    .scheme_id              resw 1
    .version                resw 1
    .timestamp              resq 1
    .keeepaliveinterval         resd 1
    .credentials            resq 2
    .ext                    resw 1
endstruc

 struc sockaddr_in
    .sin_family resw 1
    .sin_port   resw 1
    .sin_addr   resd 1
    .sin_zero   resb 8
 endstruc

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov rsi, timeval    ;   struct timespec *tp
    mov rdi, 0      ;   const clockid_t which_clock - CLOCK_REALTIME
    mov rax, 228        ;   SYS_CLOCK_GETTIME
    syscall
    pop r11
    pop rcx
    mov r8, qword [tv_sec]
    mov r9, qword [tv_usec]
    imul r8, 1000000000
    sub r8, r9
    mov qword [packet + message.timestamp], r8

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov rdi, 2      ; AF_INET
    mov rsi, 1      ; SOCK_STREAM
    mov rdx, 6      ; PROTO_TCP
    mov rax, 41     ; SYS_SOCKET
    syscall
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    cmp rax, 0
    jl exit
    mov [listen_socket], rax
    push rcx
    push r11
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rsi, 3      ;F_GETFL
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 72     ;SYS_FCNTL
    syscall         ;return 2
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov rdx, rax 
    or rdx, 2048
    mov rsi, 4      ;F_SETFL
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 72     ;SYS_FCNTL
    syscall         ; return 0
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov rsi, pop_sa     ;
    mov rdx, sockaddr_in_len    ;
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 42     ; SYS_CONNECT
    syscall         ; return -115
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov qword [tv_sec], 1
    mov qword [tv_usec], 0
    xor rsi, rsi
    mov rdi, timeout
    mov rax, 35     ;SYS_SLEEP
    syscall
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    push rcx
    push r11
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov r8, timeout
    mov r10, 0
    bts [read_fdset], rdi
    mov rdx, read_fdset
    mov rsi, read_fdset
    inc rdi
    mov rax, 23     ;SYS_SELECT
    syscall         ; 

    pop r11
    pop rcx

    push rcx
    push r11
    xor r9, r9
    xor r8, r8
    xor r10, r10
    mov rdx, 40
    mov rsi, packet
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 44     ; SYS_SENDTO
    syscall         ; return 40 - length message
    pop r11
    pop rcx

    xor r9, r9
    xor r8, r8
    xor r10, r10
    mov rdx, 512
    mov rsi, buffer
    mov rdi, [listen_socket]
    mov rax, 45     ; SYS_RECVFROM
    syscall         ; return -11
    inc rcx
    cmp rax, 0
    jne exit

exit:   
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60     ;   SYS_EXIT
    syscall
```

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, операционную систему и диалект ассемблера.

Comment: Linux 64-bit, YASM

Answer (score -1):

```
    ;; yasm -g dwarf2 -f elf64 -a x86 tcp.asm -o tcp.o
    ;; ld -o tcp tcp.o


    segment .bss

socket:     resq    1
read_fdset:     resb    2  
write_fdset:    resb    2

    segment .data

packet istruc message
        at message.length_mes,          dw  0x0020
        at message.message_id,          dw  0x1388  
        at message.scheme_id,           dw  0x4d45  
        at message.version,         dw  0x0001
        at message.timestamp,           dq  0
        at message.keeepaliveinterval,  dd  0x000003e8
        at message.credentials,         dq  0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 
        at message.ext,                 dd  0x00000000
iend

pop_sa istruc sockaddr_in
        at sockaddr_in.sin_family,  dw 2             ; AF_INET
        at sockaddr_in.sin_port,    dw 0x2823        ; 
        at sockaddr_in.sin_addr,    dd 0xf4e8d05b    ; 
        at sockaddr_in.sin_zero,    dd 0, 0
iend
sockaddr_in_len     equ $ - pop_sa


timeval: 
        tv_sec  dq 0
        tv_usec dq 0

timeout: 
        to_sec  dq 1
        to_usec dq 0 

buffer      times 2048 db 0x0

    segment .text
    global _start

_start:

struc message
    .length_mes             resw 1
    .message_id             resw 1
    .scheme_id              resw 1
    .version                resw 1
    .timestamp              resq 1
    .keeepaliveinterval     resd 1
    .credentials            resq 2
    .ext                    resd 1
endstruc

struc sockaddr_in
    .sin_family     resw 1
    .sin_port       resw 1
    .sin_addr       resd 1
    .sin_zero       resb 8
endstruc

    mov rsi, timeval    ;   struct timespec *tp
    mov rdi, 0          ;   const clockid_t which_clock - CLOCK_REALTIME
    mov rax, 228        ;   SYS_CLOCK_GETTIME
    syscall

    mov r8, qword [tv_sec]
    mov r9, qword [tv_usec]
    imul r8, 1000000000
    sub r8, r9
    mov qword [packet + message.timestamp], r8

    mov rdi, 2          ; AF_INET
    mov rsi, 1          ; SOCK_STREAM
    mov rdx, 6          ; PROTO_TCP
    mov rax, 41         ; SYS_SOCKET
    syscall

    cmp rax, 0
    jl exit
    mov [socket], rax

    xor rdx, rdx
    mov rsi, 3          ;F_GETFL
    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov rax, 72         ;SYS_FCNTL
    syscall             ;return 1

    mov rdx, rax 
    or rdx, 2048
    mov rsi, 4          ;F_SETFL
    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov rax, 72         ;SYS_FCNTL
    syscall             ; return 0

    mov rsi, pop_sa     ;
    mov rdx, sockaddr_in_len    ;
    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov rax, 42         ; SYS_CONNECT
    syscall             ; return -115

    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov qword [to_usec], 50000000
    mov qword [to_sec], 0
    mov r8,  timeout
    mov r10, 0
    bts [write_fdset], rdi
    mov rdx, write_fdset
    mov rsi, 0      ; read_fdset
    inc rdi
    mov rax, 23         ;SYS_SELECT
    syscall             ; return 1

    xor r9, r9
    xor r8, r8
    xor r10, r10
    mov rdx, 40
    mov rsi, packet
    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov rax, 44         ; SYS_SENDTO
    syscall             ; return 40 - length message

    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov qword [to_usec], 50000000
    mov qword [to_sec], 0
    mov r8,  timeout
    mov r10, 0
    bts [read_fdset], rdi
    mov rdx, 0      ; write_fdset
    mov rsi, read_fdset
    inc rdi
    mov rax, 23         ;SYS_SELECT
    syscall             ; return 1

    xor r9, r9
    xor r8, r8
    xor r10, r10
    mov rdx, 2048
    mov rsi, buffer
    mov rdi, [socket]
    mov rax, 45         ;SYS_RECVFROM
    syscall             ; 

 exit:   
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60         ;   SYS_EXIT
   syscall
```

Comment: Так в чем ошибка-то была? Вы предлагаете читателю играть сначала в "найди 5 отличий", а потом в "угадай зачем были нужны эти строчки"?

Comment: Ошибка заключалась в том, что для SENDTO() необходимо делать свой SELECT(), с размещением сокета в массиве write_fdset, а для RECFVFROM() - свой, с размещением сокета в массиве read_fdset. А не один вызов SELECT() на все.

Comment: Погодите, вы используете неблокирующие сокеты и перед каждой операцией делаете SELECT? Но зачем?!..

Comment: Чтобы перевести сокет в тот режим, который мне сейчас нужен. По-другому у меня не получается.

Comment: Зачем вам этот режим в последовательной программе?

Comment: Программа не последовательная